# how to display the list of table view as cover flow in ios6.1

Tags: uitableview, ios6, coverflow

I am new to iOS programming.I find the tutorial for displaying the image view as cover flow as shown in link http://code4app.net/ios/iCarousel-for-Cover-Flow/4f87d2db06f6e79d32000000

but my requirement is to display the list of tableviews as cover flow. Please help me.

Comment: Did you get solution for this? I just followed the answer which accepted by but I cannot scroll left or right when we start touch on UITableview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here i have used iCarousel view. After integrating the SDK(import iCarousel.h & iCarousel.m) into your application. Create ICarousel view and integrated table view in all the icarousel sub views. Here is my code

In .h file

```
iCarousel *categorySubView;
```

In .M file.

```
-(Void)createIcarousel{
                   categorySubView = [[iCarousel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 108, 480, 125)];

                    // categorySubView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
                    categorySubView.delegate = self;
                    categorySubView.dataSource = self;
                    categorySubView.type=iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
                    [self.view addSubview:categorySubView];

    }

    -(NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {

        return 10;
    }

    - (UIView *) carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{


        UITableView *sampleTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        sampleTable.dataSource = self;
        sampleTable.delegate = self;
        [sampleTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        return sampleTable;


    }

    - (BOOL)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel shouldSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{


        return YES;
    }


    - (CGFloat)carouselItemWidth:(iCarousel *)carousel
    {
        //usually this should be slightly wider than the item views
        return 180;
    }


    #pragma Table view delegate Methods



    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 10;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        }

        // Configure the cell...
    //    cell.textLabel.text = [yourarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

    }
```

Its working fine Output is like this...

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ganapathy.I got the answer.

Comment: Where did you call this(-(Void)createIcarousel) method?

Comment: That is based on ur requirement for example if u need to display the Icarousel view while loading itself place that code in viewDidLoad. I just placed that code in that button action(convert button in screen shot). hope u understand.

Comment: Nothing. Icarousel and table view's are adding programmatically no need for xib changes for this things (loading icarousal with tables)

Comment: yeah great it works fine.But when I used this with .xib file it is not working.

Comment: @Ganapathy Hey this is really good! I was just wandering, how can I do this but vertically instead of horizontally and with the cells instead of the entire UITableView??? Thanks.

Comment: @Ganapathy you cannot scroll left or right when your touches start on UITableview... have you encountered such problem ? And its solution ?