# Can not swipe when iCarousel contains UITableView as subview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, icarousel

Hi I am using `iCarousel` in my application, it will have `UITableView` as subview. When i am trying to swipe or pan to display next or previous item it is not working. I think `UITableView's` gesture recogonizer disables the iCarousel's gesture recogonizer. There are so many questions like this but i do not see any answer for this. attched is sample image[image]

Please guide me to fix this.

**code**

```
  _carousel =[[iCarousel alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
  _carousel.type = iCarouselTypeLinear;
  _carousel.pagingEnabled = YES;
  _carousel.delegate = self;
  _carousel.dataSource = self;
  [self.view addSubview:_carousel];
```

Comment: are you can't move to iCarousel  next or previous sub view?

Comment: Yes, I think you have answered for similar question

Comment: Of course.  is icarousel itself not working for you ? because that code working fine for me.

Comment: Oh, Did you notice comments for your answer one more person faced same issue

Comment: I saw just now. I didn't test that case ok i will check and update you.

Comment: I have added the tableview just half of the screen in icarousel from the bottom. When i am trying swipe from out of tableview its working

Comment: Its still working fine for me. Explain that scenario that you are facing in that code.

Comment: Can you please provide me that sample project it would be great help for me

Comment: Just do what i mentioned here, I did it same. That is my code nothing i have added. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15220578/1545180

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your carousel isn't centered which makes me think that maybe its bounds are wrong.

iCarousel doesn't have clipsToBounds enabled by default, which means that if the bounds are wrong, you will still see your item views, but may not be able to interact with them.

Try enabling clipsToBounds on the carousel, and setting the backgroundColor to something like red, so you can see if the carousel dimensions are correct.

If they aren't you may need to adjust your autoresizing or autolayout constraints.

UPDATE:

This was actually a bug in iCarousel relating to the heuristic it uses to determine if swipe gestures should be intercepted by the carousel. Fixed in beta 7.

Comment: I think some other problem is exists, tableview is placed in center of the carousel also i set clipsToBounds but not working

Comment: My mistake; this was a bug. I've fixed it in beta 7 (you can download it from github)

Comment: Thanks a lot i will do it

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel  is this link correct? I am facing same issue..I will show only one item at a time that is center item in self.view when we swipe it left or right it will show respective items its more like UIPageViewController..The problem is occurring only in centered item.. if we swipe from next or previous item it is working

Comment: Yes that's correct. I've added a table example to the tests folder to verify that it works. Is there any difference in your code versus that example that would explain why it's not working for you?